# Learn Python, exercise 6.7

Tags: python, reference

I'm reading Lutz & Ascher - Learn Python and I found this as a solution to one of the exercises:

```
class Lunch:
  def __init__(self):
    self.cust = Customer()
    self.empl = Employee()
  def order(self, foodName):
    # start a Customer order simulation
    self.cust.placeOrder(foodName, self.empl)
  def result(self):
    # ask the Customer what kind of Food it has
    self.cust.printFood()

class Customer:
  def __init__(self):
    # initialize my food to None
    self.food = None
  def placeOrder(self, foodName, employee):
    # place order with an Employee
    self.food = employee.takeOrder(foodName)
  def printFood(self):
    # print the name of my food
    print self.food.name

class Employee:
  def takeOrder(self, foodName):
    # return a Food, with requested name
    return Food(foodName)

class Food:
  def __init__(self, name):
    # store food name
    self.name = name

if __name__ == '__main__':
  x = Lunch()
  x.order('burritos')
  x.result()
  x.order('pizza')
  x.result()`
```

What I don't understand is how the definition of the method `placeOrder` inside the `customer` class works, more specifically, there is no class `employee` (just `Employee`) whose method `placeOrder` could be used.

Comment: in python, for the function definitions, you don't need to specify the types you expect being entered as parameters, you only name them. So `employee` could be also named `param_employee` (inside the function too). Then you give an instance of `Employee` to the function when you call it

Comment: Please refer the existing questions in the www.stackoverflow.com so that u will find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def placeOrder(self, foodName, employee):
    # place order with an Employee
    self.food = employee.takeOrder(foodName)
```

you may need to read a little bit about object oriented programming, and dynamic typing to grasp this. So basically, `employee` is an argument which will be passed at runtime, its type will be determined after the call to `placeOrder`. if you call `PlaceOrder` and put an instance of `Employee` or any class that has method `takeOrder()`, it will work. Imho, you should try to code an example from the beginning and test out what you learn, it will help you learn Python faster

`